# Receive notifications from Twitter to my website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter

Is there any way I can write a web application that uses JavaScript to receive twitter notifications? For example I follow a person, when that person posts a new article I will get a notification in my website application. This is giving me a lot of trouble. It would be great if I could get everyone's help

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use [Twitter's API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api).

Comment: Do I need to use a 3rd party tool for this to work? And is it too complicated? Thanks for replying to me

Comment: What is a 3rd party for you? I consider Twitter a 3rd party.
Whether it's too complicated I don't know, because I don't know how competent you are.